# Odd Error using Eclipse

Tags: java

I am working on a homework assignment where a ball is moved around the screen using left, right, up and down buttons. In addition, the ball's color is changed using green and red buttons. For some reason, my listeners are giving me the error "Btns.RightListener cannot be resolved to a type". I am not sure why.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far...

Main Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Lab2Main extends JFrame {


        Lab2Main()
    {
        setTitle("Lab 2 - Move The Ball");
        Lab2 p = new Lab2();
        add(p);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) { 

        Lab2 frame = new Lab2();
        frame.setTitle("Lab 2 - Move The Ball");
        frame.setSize(450, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }   

}
```

Class holding listeners:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Lab2 extends JFrame { 

    Btns canvas = new Btns();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JButton jbtL = new JButton("Left");
    JButton jbtR = new JButton("Right");
    JButton jbtU = new JButton("Up");
    JButton jbtD = new JButton("Down");
    JButton jbtRd = new JButton("Red");
    JButton jbtG = new JButton("Green");

    Lab2()
        {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel.add(jbtR);
        panel.add(jbtL);
        panel.add(jbtU);
        panel.add(jbtD);
        panel.add(jbtRd);
        panel.add(jbtG);

        this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jbtL.addActionListener(new Btns.LeftListener(canvas));
        jbtR.addActionListener(new Btns.RightListener(canvas));
        jbtU.addActionListener(new Btns.UpListener(canvas));
        jbtD.addActionListener(new Btns.DownListener(canvas));
        jbtRd.addActionListener(new Btns.RdColorChangeListener(canvas));
        jbtG.addActionListener(new Btns.GColorChangeListener(canvas));
        }
}
```

Class holding the buttons:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class  Btns extends JPanel
{
    int radius = 5;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (x < 0 || y < 0)
            {
                x = getWidth() / 2 -radius;
                y = getHeight() / 2 -radius;
            }
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(5,10,25,25);
    } 
    public void moveLeft()
    { 

             x -= 5; 
             this.repaint(); 
        } 

        public void moveRight()
        { 

            x += 5; 
            this.repaint(); 
        } 
        public void moveUp()
        { 

            y -= 5; 
            this.repaint(); 
        } 

        public void moveDown()
        { 
            y += 5; 
            this.repaint(); 
        } 


        public class LeftListener implements ActionListener
        { 
            private Btns canvas; 

            LeftListener(Btns canvas) 
            { 
              this.canvas = canvas; 
            } 

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            { 
             canvas.moveLeft(); 
            } 


        public class RightListener implements ActionListener
        { 
            private Btns canvas; 

            RightListener(Btns canvas) 
            { 
                this.canvas = canvas; 
            } 

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            { 
              canvas.moveRight(); 
            } 
        } 


         class UpListener implements ActionListener
         { 
            private Btns canvas; 

            UpListener(Btns canvas) 
            { 
                this.canvas = canvas; 
            } 

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            { 
                canvas.moveUp(); 
            } 
        } 



        class DownListener implements ActionListener
        { 
            private Btns canvas; 

            DownListener(Btns canvas) 
            { 
                this.canvas = canvas; 
            } 

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            { 
             canvas.moveDown(); 
            } 
        }

        class RdColorChangeListener implements ActionListener 
            { 
            private Btns canvas; 

            RdColorChangeListener(Btns canvas) { 
                this.canvas = canvas; 
            } 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
                canvas.setColor(Color.RED); 
                repaint();
            } 

        class GColorChangeListener implements ActionListener 
            { 
            private Btns canvas; 

            GColorChangeListener(Btns canvas) { 
                this.canvas = canvas; 
            } 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
                canvas.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
                repaint();
            } 
       }
    }
  }


        public void setColor(Color red) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}
```

Comment: As the [homework tag info explains] please don't add the Homework tag to new questions. Your question can be posed as is without the tag. Additionally the shorter you can make your question, the faster it will be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Btns.RightListener` (and, in fact, all the inner classes of `Btns`) need to be declared as `static` classes in order to create new instances like you are doing. Just add the `static` modifier to each class declaration. Otherwise, you would need to do something like this:

```
jbtL.addActionListener(canvas.new Btns.LeftListener(canvas));
```

Oh, and as @antlersoft points out, you need to correct the class nesting.

Comment: When I make the change you indicate above, I still get the error, "No enclosing instance of type Btns is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Btns (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Btns)."

Comment: Which change did you make? Did you declare the classes to be `static` (`public static class LeftListener...`, etc.) or did you try the qualified `canvas.new`? These are mutually exclusive options.

Comment: I changed the classes to static and that fixed the issue. If I made the canvas.new change, it gave the error again. The program now compiles and runs but the buttons are not working. I'm not sure why? I believe I have all the code there.

Comment: @KevinSchultz - First, make sure the listeners are firing. That should tell you where to look next. It doesn't look like you've updated your post with the latest code, so I can't tell what might be wrong. Did you changed all the calls to `repaint()` in your listeners to `canvas.repaint()`? (I'm assuming so; otherwise the static classes wouldn't compile.)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing } on Btns.LeftListener, so Eclipse thinks RightListener is inside of LeftListener.

Comment: That was the issue. However, when I fixed that, I got an "No enclosing instance of type Btns is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Btns (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Btns)." error?

Comment: Ted Hopp (other answer) has the answer to the enclosing instance problem